# The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, determinant, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a complex square matrix, I need to prove that the trace of $A$ is the sum of its eigenvalues.
I've already proved that, if $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial, then

$$p(x)=det(xI-A)=(x-\lambda_1)...(x-\lambda_n)=x^n-(\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n)+...+(-1)^ndet(A)$$

But I´m stuck with the proof... Thank you!

**PS:** I know that is a direct consequence of the identity $p(x)=x^n-Tr(A)+...+(-1)^ndet(A)$, but in that case, I need a proof of this identity...

Comment: Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: But I would be assuming that the matrix is diagonalizable, and that does not always happen...

Comment: You are not in fact assuming this. Look at the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Alright, I´ll read it now, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I´ve read the main ideas, but I don't see how can I use this... I think I´m missing something kind of obvious, but I really don't have any idea. Should I calculate the characteristic polynomial of the jordan matrix? How?

Comment: I think that´s it. thanks!